# Materialize datepicker range validation

Tags: jquery, datepicker, momentjs, materialize, pickadate

I am using materialize datepicker for selecting start and end date in my application. In that, I am in need of allowing user to select only the start and end date of a **quarter** (Example: start date - March 31, 2016 and end date - June 30, 2016), otherwise an error message should be displayed. There is no restriction in the year selection.

Example: if user selects start date: June 2, 2015 and end date: Aug 4, 2015. In this case, I have to display an error message.

I have started trying this in following JSFiddle link, but I am unable to achieve this.

```
[JSFiddle][1]
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/7ujbv2yz/12/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`endOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) to get the start and the end of the quarter. Using [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) you can convert moment object to JavaScript Date and pass it to `min` and `max`.

To perform an action after user selects a date use [`onSet`](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#events) property.

Here a live example:

```js
$('#date1').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 15,
  onSet: function(obj){
    var picker2 = $('#date2').pickadate('picker');
    if( obj.select ){
      var val = moment(obj.select);
      picker2.set('min', val.startOf('quarter').toDate());
      picker2.set('max', val.endOf('quarter').toDate());
    }
    
    if( obj.clear ){
      picker2.set('min', false);
      picker2.set('max', false);
    }
  }
});

$('#date2').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 15,
  onSet: function(obj){
    var picker1 = $('#date1').pickadate('picker');
    if( obj.select ){
      var val = moment(obj.select);
      picker1.set('min', val.startOf('quarter').toDate());
      picker1.set('max', val.endOf('quarter').toDate());
    }
    
    if( obj.clear ){
      picker1.set('min', false);
      picker1.set('max', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col m6">
  <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;">From Date:</span>
  <input type="date" id="date1" name="date1" class="datepicker" style="display:inline-block;width:40%;">
</div>
<div class="col m6">
  <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;">To Date:</span>
  <input type="date" id="date2" name="date2" class="datepicker" style="display:inline-block;width:40%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the mentioned code is allowing me to select any date range. how to restrict that to select only the quarter start and end dates?

Comment: Why do say that any date range is allowed? Running the snippet I can select only dates of the current quarter (from 01-01-2017 to 31-03-2017).

Comment: yes.. This code is working fine for current quarter. But In my application , there is no year restriction. User can select any year , only the restriction is allowing them to select start and end date of a quarter

Comment: ok, that was not clear to me, maybe you can edit your question to clarify further your requirement. Anyway, how you determine which quarter should be enabled?

Comment: we can fix the quarters starting from jan-mar, apr-june,july-sep and oct-dec. For example, if I select any day in the month of feb it should consider the fisrt quarter

Comment: I've updated my answer, changing the code in the snippet, let me know if it matches your requirements.